# How do I "map" certain return value of a script to "yellow" status in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, errorlevel

In Jenkins there is a possibility to create free project which can contain a script execution. The build fails (becomes red) when the return level of the script is not 0.

**Is there a possibility to make it "yellow"?**
*(Yellow usually indicates successful build with failed tests)*

The system runs on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the [Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) a try. That should do the trick for you.

Comment: I don't see where it mentions checking return values in the documentation for the Log Parser Plugin. Could you please point this out?

Answer (score 0):

One slightly hacky way do do it, is to alter the job to publish test results and supply fake results.

I've got a job that is publishing the test results from a file called "results.xml".  The last step in my build script checks the return value of the build, copies eihter "results-good.xml" or "results-unstable.xml" to "results.xml" and then returns a zero.

Thus if the script fails on one of the early steps, the build is red.  But if the build succeeds its green or yellow based on the return code it would have retunred without this hack.

Comment: Thank's for the idea, but I'm going to use the other answerer's hint with that plugin, it sounds more simple.

Comment: @IviviVavava - Thats OK. Given the choice I'd probably use the Log Parser plugin too.  I'm only using this hack on an isoslated system with no internet and no easy access to add new software.